# time.sleep not working per item in range or list

Tags: python

I was trying to make a code like this

```
def no(t=.001):
    print("N", end='')
    for i in range(1000):
        print('o', end='')
        time.sleep(t)
    print()
```

So that when I call `no()` I would print a long "Nooooo...", waiting some time between each 'o'.
What happens instead is that the function halts, for the whole total time (1 second with the default argument), then prints the whole list.
Is this intended? And if not how should I obtain my intended effect?

Comment: `print(..., flush=True)`

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that python is actually printing all the characters in exactly the same way that you intend - it writes the `N`, then an `o` per second to stdout. The issue is that the operating system does not display it because the file (stdout is a file) is not flushed. This typically automatically happens when `\n` is printed (by default, at the end of the printed string), but you'd overwritten that with `end==''`.

Luckily, `print` has an optional `flush` argument that you can use to force a flush. So you should be able to fix your behavior with this:

```
def no(t=.001):
    print("N", end='', flush=True)
    for i in range(1000):
        print('o', end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(t)
    print()
```